# Interior LED stops working

Tags: electrical, led

Built a new house a year ago and installed all LED lights. Everything working as it should. Had a power outage and one LED fixture wouldn’t come on. I replaced it with a new fixture that takes bulbs, works fine. Had another power outage today and the wife calls and says 2 LED fixtures won’t work.

Why is this happening? Can I fix a LED fixture?

Answer (score 1):

If your LED is an integrated package, rather than a series of sockets into which you insert bulbs, it would indicate that the electronics of the device has failed due to the surge-like return of the power. LED illuminator devices at the board level are quite reliable and resistant, but the power circuits, especially on the lower cost devices are not quite so reliable.

I have a number of bulb-type lamps, all with LED units. A storm in the not-too-distant past caused quite a few power flickers and I had to replace too many of the bulbs. I disassembled a few and found that the LED portion worked fine when fed with an external DC power supply, which left the un-repairable power circuitry as the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the information, very helpful. I’ll install new led lights